AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'turtlesize' on line 23 in main.py
import turtle

drawTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
drawTurtle.shape("turtle")
drawTurtle.speed(500)
drawTurtle.hideturtle()
drawTurtle.penup()
drawTurtle.goto(180,65)
drawTurtle.pendown()
drawTurtle.goto(-180, 65)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, 65)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, 155)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, -180)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(-180, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(180, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(75, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(75, -180)
drawTurtle.goto(75, 155)
getClickedturtle = turtle.Turtle()
getClickedturtle.shape("square")
getClickedturtle.turtlesize(stretch_wid=100, stretch_len=100, outline=100)

def getcords(x, y):
  print(x, y)
  drawTurtle.goto(x, y)
getClickedturtle.onclick(getcords)

im trying to make the turtle size bigger but its not working
im using turtle trinket
this error shows up
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'turtlesize' on line 23 in main.py
im trying to make the turtle size bigger but its not working

How are you running this code?  Does it run on your local computer, or in an online hosted environment (such as repl.it) ?

i just started coding i have no idea what most of this means, but if it helps im running it on google in turtle trinket

Trinket doesn't use the standard turtle module (which would be very difficult to make appear on a web page), and .turtlesize() appears to be one of the methods that is missing in their implementation.  Unfortunately, I don't see any equivalent in their documentation.

A useful starter reference can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html.

i have moved my code to pycharm and now the turtlesize works but onscreenclick() doest (same problem)
getClickedTurtle.onscreenclick(getcords)
i also tried
turtle.onscreenclick(getcords)
and there was no error it just didnt work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should use shapesize instead of turtlesize but first set resizemode to "user" to adapt the appearance of the turtle according to the values of stretchfactor and outlinewidth set by shapesize.ReplacegetClickedturtle.turtlesize(stretch_wid=100, stretch_len=100, outline=100)by
getClickedturtle.resizemode("user") 
getClickedturtle.shapesize(stretch_wid=100, stretch_len=100, outline=100)

Hope it works.


i have moved my code to pycharm and now the turtlesize works but
onscreenclick() doest (same problem)
getClickedTurtle.onscreenclick(getcords) i also tried
turtle.onscreenclick(getcords) and there was no error it just didnt
work

Since onscreenclick() is setting a screen method, let's apply it to the screen instance rather than a turtle:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

drawTurtle = Turtle()
drawTurtle.hideturtle()
drawTurtle.speed(0)

drawTurtle.penup()
drawTurtle.goto(180, 65)
drawTurtle.pendown()

drawTurtle.goto(-180, 65)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, 65)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, 155)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, -180)
drawTurtle.goto(-75, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(-180, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(180, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(75, -75)
drawTurtle.goto(75, -180)
drawTurtle.goto(75, 155)

drawTurtle.shape('turtle')
drawTurtle.showturtle()

def getcords(x, y):
    print(x, y)
    drawTurtle.goto(x, y)

screen.onclick(getcords)

screen.mainloop()

